# Convert the results of IQueryable to a string to display in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, ado.net-entity-data-model

Using C#, WPF, .NET 4.5
In my program, I am trying to populate the value of a TextBox from a database. The value is obtained by a LINQ statement. I've tried all different things such as `To.String()` and `Console.WriteLine()` etc.  If you can figure out a way to make this work that would be awesome, if you can find a better way to select the data and display it, i would be interested in that as well.
C# Code:

```
private AuroraEntities auroraContext = null;    
private void LoadTB()
    { 
     this.auroraContext = new AuroraEntities();
     ObjectQuery<Inventory> inventories = auroraContext.Inventories;
     string name = ingNameCB.SelectedValue.ToString();  
     var queryResult = (from q in inventories
                        where q.InventoryName == name                          
                        select q);

    textBox1.DataContext = queryResult.ToString();
    }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="70,186,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=InventoryName, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you expecting a single result? If so, use [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535183.aspx), or [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156472.aspx), or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301896.aspx) to obtain a single `Inventory` item (which of these options is most appropriate will depend on your situation). However, you will then have an `Inventory` item, an `Inventory.ToString()` may well not give you what you want either.

What *are* you trying to display from the inventory? Its name? Its description? Perhaps a combination? You should think about that very carefully - once you've decided what you're actually trying to achieve, writing the code for it is likely to be quite simple.

If your query could return multiple results, you've got even more to think about. Does it even make sense to have a single textbox? Perhaps you should be populating a table of some kind?

Comment: thanks for the tip.  I would be returning only a single instance of InventoryName from the database. Eventually this would be bound to a Combobox, and changing that would populate the various TextBoxes associated with each column in the table, but this definately got me on my way and it is populating with a value now!  Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
(from q in inventories
 where q.InventoryName == name                          
 select q).FirstOrDefault().InventoryName;
```

You need also to check if `FirstOrDefault()` is not null

Comment: Watch out for the possible null exception if the query resulted in no results.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try it like this

```
var result = queryResult.FirstOrDefault();
textBox1.Text=result==null ? string.Empty :result.InventoryName;
```

I think there is no point of doing binding if your InventoryName dont fire NotifyPropertyChanged so its better you directly assign Text instead of DataContext

Comment: Eventually i will be doing databinding to comboboxes, but that is a way down the road.  Thanks for the help!